# pssh + verify date between machines and alert if date difference is more then 3 second

Tags: awk, sed, perl, date, parallel-ssh

we are using the following great pssh command in order to see if time differences is more then 3 second between machines

```
 pssh -i -o /tmp/out/ -e /tmp/err/ -H "master01 master02 master03 worker01 worker02" -l root -x '-q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes' date
[1] 12:15:43 [SUCCESS] worker02
Fri Jul 12 12:15:43 UTC 2019
[2] 12:15:43 [SUCCESS] master03
Fri Jul 12 12:15:43 UTC 2019
[3] 12:15:43 [SUCCESS] worker01
Fri Jul 12 12:15:43 UTC 2019
[4] 12:15:43 [SUCCESS] master01
Fri Jul 12 12:15:43 UTC 2019
[5] 12:15:43 [SUCCESS] master02
Fri Jul 12 12:15:43 UTC 2019
```

now we want to set pssh in the bash script

and we want to check that time isn't more then **3 second** between machines

how to use awk/perl one liner /bash/ , in order to verify time isn't more then 3 sec?

**Or in order to show only the date results:**

```
pssh -i -H "master01 master02 master03 worker01 worker02" 2>/dev/null -l root -x '-q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes' date | grep -v "^\["
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
```

Note - we have more then 452 redhat 7.2 machines in our cluster ( the below is example )

Comment: Well presumably the first step would be to change the date format to epoch seconds `+%s` (or perhaps nanoseconds) - then you can pipe the results to any simple min/max routine (search here for *awk min max* for examples) - or even something like `datamash range 1`

Comment: can you give an answer with the solution , so all folks will enjoy

Comment: would it be reasonable to compare all the target system dates to the date on the system you're running pssh from? (considering the possibility of passing the date out to the remote systems and asking if their date is more than 3 seconds off) -- just a simpler alternative, if it fits your situation.

Comment: yes is simple and good idea , to compare the current ,machine date with all others remote and see if remote machine are more then 3 second , so in that case can you suggest code for that example?